# Stored passwords and scheduled tasks in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows, scheduled-task, windows-server-2003-r2

In general, if you are `PC\Admin` and you have a stored password for network share `DOMAINSERVER\Share` (done using the interface "Stored User Names and Passwords"), and you have a scheduled task that runs as you even when you are not logged in, will a script that uses, say, `xcopy` be able to copy over to that share drive using your credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work.  When you schedule the Task, you can specify a user and password to use when the task runs,  use the Domain\user and password.   I prefer to create special accounts for this, as if you use a user's acct (your own) and the password changes, the tasks will fail.  SO I create a account just for scheduled tasks, set a really long password,  limit the rights to the bare minimum, and exempt it from the password expiration that my domain users have.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon so.  Never tested it, but when the process impersonates you, it should be able to reference your stored credentials.  It's easy to test... why not try it.